# AWS elastic search access - using Presigned URL

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elasticsearch

I'm using presigned URL with the generated aws signature and I can able to get default search responses like _search. But, I'm unable to query it. Below is my presigned URL :-

https://domain-endpoint/index/_search?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=AKID%2Fus-east-1%2Fes%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20151229T101818Z&X-Amz-Expires=90&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Signature=signature

Please help me, where I need to specify my query. i.e name:a*